# How do I retrieve data from google map API's

Tags: php, xml

I am trying to retrieve the long and lat values by converting a place name (E.g. london) into lang and lat values.
I am using this API:
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=

Here is the request:
maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=london&sensor=false

This is the XML document it gives back to me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<GeocodeResponse>
 <status>OK</status>
 <result>
  <type>locality</type>
  <type>political</type>
  <formatted_address>London, UK</formatted_address>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>London</long_name>
   <short_name>London</short_name>
   <type>locality</type>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>England</long_name>
   <short_name>England</short_name>
   <type>administrative_area_level_1</type>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>United Kingdom</long_name>
   <short_name>GB</short_name>
   <type>country</type>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>London</long_name>
   <short_name>London</short_name>
   <type>postal_town</type>
  </address_component>
  <geometry>
   <location>
    <lat>51.5081289</lat>
    <lng>-0.1280050</lng>
   </location>
   <location_type>APPROXIMATE</location_type>
   <viewport>
    <southwest>
     <lat>51.3968770</lat>
     <lng>-0.3841238</lng>
    </southwest>
    <northeast>
     <lat>51.6191098</lat>
     <lng>0.1281138</lng>
    </northeast>
   </viewport>
   <bounds>
    <southwest>
     <lat>51.3849401</lat>
     <lng>-0.3514684</lng>
    </southwest>
    <northeast>
     <lat>51.6723432</lat>
     <lng>0.1482710</lng>
    </northeast>
   </bounds>
  </geometry>
 </result>
 <result>
  <type>locality</type>
  <type>political</type>
  <formatted_address>London, ON, Canada</formatted_address>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>London</long_name>
   <short_name>London</short_name>
   <type>locality</type>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>Middlesex County</long_name>
   <short_name>Middlesex County</short_name>
   <type>administrative_area_level_2</type>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>Ontario</long_name>
   <short_name>ON</short_name>
   <type>administrative_area_level_1</type>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>Canada</long_name>
   <short_name>CA</short_name>
   <type>country</type>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
  <geometry>
   <location>
    <lat>42.9793980</lat>
    <lng>-81.2461380</lng>
   </location>
   <location_type>APPROXIMATE</location_type>
   <viewport>
    <southwest>
     <lat>42.8245170</lat>
     <lng>-81.3908520</lng>
    </southwest>
    <northeast>
     <lat>43.0732450</lat>
     <lng>-81.1063880</lng>
    </northeast>
   </viewport>
   <bounds>
    <southwest>
     <lat>42.8245170</lat>
     <lng>-81.3908520</lng>
    </southwest>
    <northeast>
     <lat>43.0732450</lat>
     <lng>-81.1063880</lng>
    </northeast>
   </bounds>
  </geometry>
 </result>
 <result>
  <type>locality</type>
  <type>political</type>
  <formatted_address>London, KY, USA</formatted_address>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>London</long_name>
   <short_name>London</short_name>
   <type>locality</type>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>Laurel</long_name>
   <short_name>Laurel</short_name>
   <type>administrative_area_level_2</type>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>Kentucky</long_name>
   <short_name>KY</short_name>
   <type>administrative_area_level_1</type>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>United States</long_name>
   <short_name>US</short_name>
   <type>country</type>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
  <geometry>
   <location>
    <lat>37.1289771</lat>
    <lng>-84.0832646</lng>
   </location>
   <location_type>APPROXIMATE</location_type>
   <viewport>
    <southwest>
     <lat>37.0797589</lat>
     <lng>-84.1262620</lng>
    </southwest>
    <northeast>
     <lat>37.1522600</lat>
     <lng>-84.0359570</lng>
    </northeast>
   </viewport>
   <bounds>
    <southwest>
     <lat>37.0797589</lat>
     <lng>-84.1262620</lng>
    </southwest>
    <northeast>
     <lat>37.1522600</lat>
     <lng>-84.0359570</lng>
    </northeast>
   </bounds>
  </geometry>
 </result>
 <result>
  <type>locality</type>
  <type>political</type>
  <formatted_address>London, OH 43140, USA</formatted_address>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>London</long_name>
   <short_name>London</short_name>
   <type>locality</type>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>Madison</long_name>
   <short_name>Madison</short_name>
   <type>administrative_area_level_2</type>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>Ohio</long_name>
   <short_name>OH</short_name>
   <type>administrative_area_level_1</type>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>United States</long_name>
   <short_name>US</short_name>
   <type>country</type>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>43140</long_name>
   <short_name>43140</short_name>
   <type>postal_code</type>
  </address_component>
  <geometry>
   <location>
    <lat>39.8864493</lat>
    <lng>-83.4482529</lng>
   </location>
   <location_type>APPROXIMATE</location_type>
   <viewport>
    <southwest>
     <lat>39.8592800</lat>
     <lng>-83.4789230</lng>
    </southwest>
    <northeast>
     <lat>39.9217860</lat>
     <lng>-83.3899969</lng>
    </northeast>
   </viewport>
   <bounds>
    <southwest>
     <lat>39.8592800</lat>
     <lng>-83.4789230</lng>
    </southwest>
    <northeast>
     <lat>39.9217860</lat>
     <lng>-83.3899969</lng>
    </northeast>
   </bounds>
  </geometry>
 </result>
</GeocodeResponse>
```

I am parsing the XML with PHP.
Here is my code:

```
$geoResponce = new SimpleXMLElement($response);
$geoLocatonLat = $geoResponce->result[0]->geometry->location->lat;
```

But I just get null values
Can you tell me where I am going wrong please.  Thanks

ADDITION:
here is my var_dump($geoResponce);

```
ssobject(SimpleXMLElement)#108 (2) {
  ["status"]=>
  string(2) "OK"
  ["result"]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#120 (5) {
    ["type"]=>
    string(5) "route"
    ["formatted_address"]=>
    string(32) "Eldonian Way, Liverpool L3 6, UK"
    ["address_component"]=>
    array(8) {
      [0]=>
      object(SimpleXMLElement)#121 (3) {
        ["long_name"]=>
        string(12) "Eldonian Way"
        ["short_name"]=>
        string(12) "Eldonian Way"
        ["type"]=>
        string(5) "route"
      }
      [1]=>
      object(SimpleXMLElement)#122 (3) {
        ["long_name"]=>
        string(9) "Liverpool"
        ["short_name"]=>
        string(9) "Liverpool"
        ["type"]=>
        array(2) {
          [0]=>
          string(8) "locality"
          [1]=>
          string(9) "political"
        }
      }
      [2]=>
      object(SimpleXMLElement)#123 (3) {
        ["long_name"]=>
        string(9) "Liverpool"
        ["short_name"]=>
        string(9) "Liverpool"
        ["type"]=>
        array(2) {
          [0]=>
          string(27) "administrative_area_level_3"
          [1]=>
          string(9) "political"
        }
      }
      [3]=>
      object(SimpleXMLElement)#124 (3) {
        ["long_name"]=>
        string(9) "Liverpool"
        ["short_name"]=>
        string(9) "Liverpool"
        ["type"]=>
        array(2) {
          [0]=>
          string(27) "administrative_area_level_2"
          [1]=>
          string(9) "political"
        }
      }
      [4]=>
      object(SimpleXMLElement)#125 (3) {
        ["long_name"]=>
        string(7) "England"
        ["short_name"]=>
        string(7) "England"
        ["type"]=>
        array(2) {
          [0]=>
          string(27) "administrative_area_level_1"
          [1]=>
          string(9) "political"
        }
      }
      [5]=>
      object(SimpleXMLElement)#126 (3) {
        ["long_name"]=>
        string(14) "United Kingdom"
        ["short_name"]=>
        string(2) "GB"
        ["type"]=>
        array(2) {
          [0]=>
          string(7) "country"
          [1]=>
          string(9) "political"
        }
      }
      [6]=>
      object(SimpleXMLElement)#127 (3) {
        ["long_name"]=>
        string(4) "L3 6"
        ["short_name"]=>
        string(4) "L3 6"
        ["type"]=>
        array(2) {
          [0]=>
          string(18) "postal_code_prefix"
          [1]=>
          string(11) "postal_code"
        }
      }
      [7]=>
      object(SimpleXMLElement)#128 (3) {
        ["long_name"]=>
        string(9) "Liverpool"
        ["short_name"]=>
        string(9) "Liverpool"
        ["type"]=>
        string(11) "postal_town"
      }
    }
    ["geometry"]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#129 (4) {
      ["location"]=>
      object(SimpleXMLElement)#130 (2) {
        ["lat"]=>
        string(10) "53.4189242"
        ["lng"]=>
        string(10) "-2.9926240"
      }
      ["location_type"]=>
      string(16) "GEOMETRIC_CENTER"
      ["viewport"]=>
      object(SimpleXMLElement)#131 (2) {
        ["southwest"]=>
        object(SimpleXMLElement)#133 (2) {
          ["lat"]=>
          string(10) "53.4171964"
          ["lng"]=>
          string(10) "-2.9940368"
        }
        ["northeast"]=>
        object(SimpleXMLElement)#134 (2) {
          ["lat"]=>
          string(10) "53.4208640"
          ["lng"]=>
          string(10) "-2.9913388"
        }
      }
      ["bounds"]=>
      object(SimpleXMLElement)#132 (2) {
        ["southwest"]=>
        object(SimpleXMLElement)#134 (2) {
          ["lat"]=>
          string(10) "53.4171964"
          ["lng"]=>
          string(10) "-2.9934545"
        }
        ["northeast"]=>
        object(SimpleXMLElement)#133 (2) {
          ["lat"]=>
          string(10) "53.4208640"
          ["lng"]=>
          string(10) "-2.9919211"
        }
      }
    }
    ["partial_match"]=>
    string(4) "true"
  }
}
enter code here
enter code here
enter code here
```

Comment: Can you add to your question the var_dump result of $geoResponce object ?

Comment: just done it  
please take a look
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
 $geoResponce = simplexml_load_string($response);
 $geoLocatonLat = $geoResponce->result[0]->geometry->location->lat;
```

it will print 51.5081289

you can repeat it with lng element

Comment: This did not work for me.  
It keeps saying: "The field 'result' is not found...."  
Any other ideas? Thanks

Comment: interesting because if you are operating on the above mentioned XML the above should work. the vardump i think only shows one result object so your can try this instead. I am online now if you are we can work it off

`$geoResponce = simplexml_load_string($response);`

`echo  $geoLocatonLat = $geoResponce->result->geometry->location->lat;`

Comment: can you change the output from var_dump to print_r output. mind you you have to change `$response` to `$geoResponce`

Comment: affect the XML string first to a variable, then pass it to simplexml_load_string function, if the XML is well formatted as the one you pasted in the question, the code added by Jaspreet should work without any problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here is function to receive data from google by Json

```
// The Google Geocoding API url used to get the JSON data
var geocodingAPI = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&sensor=true";

$.getJSON(geocodingAPI, function (json) {

    // Set the variables from the results array
    var address = json.results[0].formatted_address;
   // console.log('Address : ', address);

    var latitude = json.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
   // console.log('Latitude : ', latitude);

    var longitude = json.results[0].geometry.location.lng;
  //  console.log('Longitude : ', longitude);

    // Set the table td text
    $('#address').text(address);
    $('#latitude').text(latitude);
    $('#longitude').text(longitude);
});
```

You can call this function any where on your website

See example here: http://www.uscompanies.biz/biz-ar-11075.html